# Creating one exe file out of visual studio project with external DLL files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, dll, exe

So I have a visual studio project with some external DLL files. I know about the option to build then search for the built file in debug folder. As it is right now, those external DLL files are outside of my exe file, and the exe file cannot be run if they're not in the same folder... So my question is: is there any way for me to incorporate all those external DLL files into one EXE file?

Thanks alot !

Comment: Have you considered creating an installer for your project? You can do this using [WIX](http://wixtoolset.org/) or using [install shield LE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531020.aspx)?

Comment: Unrelated: This is how [alot](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html) looks like for those who don't know :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov hahahaha thanks for the article, loved it ! :D